# JSONPath - How to query an attribute with a period in it

Tags: jsonpath

My JSON is just:

```
{
    "https://example.com/external_id": 99999
}
```

But I can't extract the 99999 for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Right [in the documentation](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2):

```
$['https://example.com/external_id']
```

Tried using http://jsonpath.com/.